# Number of combinations from a set with repeated items

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In trying to solve the problem stated below, I'm not sure how I can find the total number of combinations possible?

"*Find the probability that 3 vowels and 2 consonants are chosen when five letters are chosen at random from the word CALCULATOR*"

In general, how would I find the total number of combinations of choosing a group of *n* objects from a set of more than *n* objects where there are repeated objects in that set?

Comment: Based on the problem statement, I would view the letters of the word CALCULATOR as the [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $\{2 \cdot C, 2 \cdot A, 2 \cdot L, 1 \cdot U, 1 \cdot T, 1 \cdot O, 1 \cdot R\}$.  That way you are selecting $3$ vowels from $4$ vowels and $2$ consonants from $6$ consonants.

Comment: But there are 4 distinct consonants, and  3 distinct vowels. Would the subset AAOCC (any order) qualify as meeting the criterion? Or does it need to be something like AOUCL?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question since all the letters of the word DAUGHTER are distinct.